How to remove all spaces and punctuation in a string so the code will recognize palindromes?
It took me a moment to figure out what was going on because I was using a single word for testing the code, but it can ignore the punctuation. I can't figure out why, but for some reason it will ignore the spaces or the punctuation, but not at the same time. While looking for the problem I did change the
****replaceAll("\p{Punct}", "");
to
****replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]+", "")
Though it seems to do the same thing. But the problem I run into here is that the program recognizes certain things but not others. And I have tried separating the code into two parts, first to remove the punctuation and the second to remove spaces, both with the same result.
an example is that "pop", "Pop", "P op", "P op!" does work, but others like "Never odd, or even!" doesn't.
I don't even know where to go with this, could you point me in the right direction?
import java.util.Scanner;

class Palindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("CSE110 Palindrome - TAOLIN DEINIOL\n");

        String userInput;
        while (true) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input statement, or type'done' to quit:");
            userInput = in.next();      
            userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
            userInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");
            userInput= userInput.replaceAll(" ", "");
            if (userInput.equals("done")) {
                break;
            }


            Palindrome(userInput);
        }
    }

    public static boolean Palindrome(int i, int j, String A) {

        if (i >= j) {
            System.out.println("That is a Palindrome.\n");
            return true;
        }
        if (A.charAt(i) != A.charAt(j)) {
            System.out.println("That is NOT a Palindrome.\n");
            return false;
        }
        return Palindrome(i + 1, j - 1, A);
    }

    public static boolean Palindrome(String A) {
        return Palindrome(0, A.length() - 1, A);
    }
}


Your question has been answered, but here's an additional minor suggestion. It's unconventional to have normal methods named the same as the enclosing class. In this case, you've got a method called "Palindrome". At first, I thought it was a constructor, but then realised it wasn't. To avoid confusion, use the recommended naming conventions: as it's a Boolean method, it should preferably be called isPalindrome. And it shouldn't print anything itself, but instead do the printing in main after checking the returned value.

"seems to do the same thing" - no, one is eliminating only punctuation, while the second is replacing everything but the given characters, that is, not only eliminating punctuation but also digits, symbols, spaces and more

You'd be better off reading lines with your Scanner as palindromes are often sentences (the interesting ones anyway). You can then do String s = userInput.codePoints().map(Character::toLowerCase).filter(Character::isAlphabetic).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());boolean isPalindrome = s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()); That's it

By the way, the char type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters. Learn to use code point integers instead, as shown in Comment by g00se.

Palindrome problems are usually given as learning exercises and therefore using StringBuilder.reverse is cheating. Besides, using StringBuilder.reverse actually does twice the work needed to check a palindrome. You only need to check the first half of the string against the second half of the string, not the whole string against its reverse.

Apparently this is java question, not javascript.
A good way to find out why your code does not do what you think it should do is to debug it. Every modern IDE can help you with that. Or just print the value of the relevant variables (here userInput) after every modification.
After that you will see, that userInput has just the value "Never", after you typed Never odd, or even!. That's because in.next() gives you the next token (which is the next word). If you replace this with in.nextLine() the code works as expected. So the problem had nothing to do with the replaceAll call.

Thanks! that worked. Its mind boggling that something that small diverted all the code like that.

I have made a few corrections to your program, and one addition.
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

   public void init() {
      System.out.println( "CSE110 Palindrome - TAOLIN DEINIOL\n" );    
      String userInput;
      while( true ) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
         System.out.println( "Input statement, or type'done' to quit:" );

           // change "next" to "nextLine", to read a complete entry
         userInput = in.nextLine();
         userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
         userInput = userInput.replaceAll( "\\p{Punct}", "" );

           // remove accents and other modifiers
         userInput = Normalizer.normalize( userInput, Normalizer.Form.NFD )
                .replaceAll( "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "" );
         System.out.println( userInput );
         userInput = userInput.replaceAll( " ", "" );
         System.out.println( userInput );
         if( userInput.equals( "done" ) ) {
            break;
         }

           // remove the intermediate step, call directly to "isPalindrome"
           // change the name of this method, to avoid collision with the name of the class
         isPalindrome( 0, userInput.length() -1, userInput );
      }
   }

   public boolean isPalindrome( int i, int j, String A ) {
      if( i >= j ) {
         System.out.println( "That is a Palindrome.\n" );
         return true;
      }
      if( A.charAt( i ) != A.charAt( j ) ) {
         System.out.println( "That is NOT a Palindrome.\n" );
         return false;
      }
      return isPalindrome( i + 1, j - 1, A );
   }


   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Palindrome aa = new Palindrome();
      aa.init();
   }
}

In the main metod, only create the object Palindrome and call to your metod init, that way I avoid the ugly (unnecessary) static.

This works by removing all non-letters [^a-z] (by replacing with with nothing) and uses StringBuilder to reverse the characters:
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Input statement, or type 'done' to quit:");
    String userInput = in.nextLine();
    if (userInput.equals("done")) {
        break;
    }
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
    boolean isPalindrome = new StringBuilder(userInput).reverse().toString().equals(userInput);
    System.out.format("%s is%s a palindrome\n", userInput, isPalindrome ? "" : " not");
}

